# How to store a string from YAML::Node in a class using template decoding

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdstring, yaml-cpp

I have been trying to implement some convert structs for yaml-cpp for my own data types. Of which one is a class, not just a struct. The encode function works fine. But the decode function doesn't. I try to get a string from a yaml file and set the correct variable in the class.

```
template<>
struct convert<EngineNode*> {
  static Node encode(EngineNode *rhs) {
    Node node;
    std::string type;
    if(rhs->type == 0) {
        type = "node";
    } else if(rhs->type == 1) {
        type = "scene";
    } else if(rhs->type == 3) {
        type = "particle";
    }
    node[type]["name"] = rhs->name;
    node[type]["type"] = rhs->type;
    node[type]["velocity"] = rhs->getVelocity();
    node[type]["position"] = rhs->getPosition();
    node[type]["rotation"] = rhs->getRotation();

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < rhs->children.size(); i++) {
        if(rhs->children[i]->type == SPRITE) {
            node[type]["children"].push_back((SpriteNode*)rhs->children[i]);
        } else {
            node[type]["children"].push_back(rhs->children[i]);
        }
    }
    return node;
  }

  static bool decode(const Node& node, EngineNode *rhs) {
    if((!node["root"]["node"].IsDefined()) && (!node["root"]["scene"].IsDefined()) && (!node["particle"].IsDefined())) {
        return false;
    }
    std::string type;

    if(node["root"]["node"].IsDefined()) {
        type = "node";       
    } else if(node["root"]["scene"].IsDefined()) {
        type = "scene";
    }
    const Node n = node["root"][type];

    rhs->name = n["name"].as<std::string>();
    rhs->type = n["type"].as<int>();
    rhs->setVelocity(n["velocity"].as<Velocity>());
    rhs->setPosition(n["position"].as<Point>());
    rhs->setRotation(n["rotation"].as<float>());

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n["children"].size(); i++) {
        if(n["children"]["type"].as<int>() == SPRITE) {
            rhs->addChild(n["children"].as<SpriteNode*>());
        } else {
            rhs->addChild(n["children"].as<EngineNode*>());
        }
    }

    return true;
  }
};
```

If you want to look at the full source its at [github](https://github.com/blackwolf12333/randomengine2/blob/yaml-parser).

The problem is that it segfaults with the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73e3b5c in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff73e3b5c in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x000000000040f590 in YAML::convert<EngineNode*>::decode (node=..., rhs=0x8) at src/yaml_config.cpp:90
#2  0x000000000040ef9f in YAML::as_if<EngineNode*, void>::operator() (this=0x7fffffffe4c0) at /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:119
#3  0x0000000000407a7d in YAML::Node::as<EngineNode*> (this=0x7fffffffe5c8) at /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:143
#4  0x00000000004074f9 in YamlConfig::readNode (this=0x8cf810, yaml_node=...) at src/yaml_config.cpp:172
#5  0x000000000040739a in YamlConfig::read (this=0x8cf810, path=...) at src/yaml_config.cpp:161
#6  0x0000000000404fa5 in GameScene::GameScene (this=0x8d62d0) at game/gamescene.cpp:16
#7  0x0000000000404205 in Main::initGameScene (this=0x61d2b0) at src/main.cpp:75
#8  0x0000000000404480 in main () at src/main.cpp:145
```

I can't figure out why that happens, it's probably not related to yaml-cpp at all but just my very limited understanding of templates and other stuff that's used here. (I only know very basic c++)

Any help would be appreciated,

Peter

Comment: From the backtrace, it looks like the `rhs` pointer was at address `0x8` when `decode` was called. That's probably not a valid address. Are you sure `rhs` was allocated correctly before passing it to the YAML decoder?

Comment: Also, which line above is line 90 in the original file?

Comment: Line 90 is the line with rhs->name = n["name"].as<std::string>(); I have no idea where or how rhs should be allocated, so yeah, that's probably the problem. I thought about that, but I don't know where I should allocated it. In the decode function?

Comment: It would only work there if you could pass a pointer to the pointer, since you would get a pointer back from the `new` operator, and that would then need to be passed back to the caller. I would rather have the caller allocate the `rhs` like they do for the `encode` function.

Comment: How do you mean "have the caller allocate rhs".

Comment: In order to answer that question, I had to search the code for `Node::as<T>` to figure out how your function is being called. Basically, you need to rework your code to use references rather than pointers. Then the `as` function would allocate an `EngineNode` on the stack and the copy-constructor would be invoked on assignment. I'll work on an example for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Node::as<T>` function allocates a variable of type `T` on the stack and then uses copy semantics to return the converted value. In the above case, `T` is `EngineNode *`, which is a pointer to an `EngineNode`. The `as` function does not allocate additional memory for an actual `EngineNode`, so dereferencing (using `*` or `->`) results in a segmentation fault.

The fix would be to rework your conversion functions to use references instead of pointers:

```
template<>
struct convert<EngineNode> {
  static Node encode(const EngineNode &rhs) {
    Node node;
    std::string type;
    if(rhs.type == 0) {
        type = "node";
    } else if(rhs.type == 1) {
        type = "scene";
    } else if(rhs.type == 3) {
        type = "particle";
    }    

    // ...
  }

  static bool decode(const Node& node, EngineNode &rhs) {
    if((!node["root"]["node"].IsDefined()) && (!node["root"]["scene"].IsDefined()) && (!node["particle"].IsDefined())) {
    return false;
    }
    std::string type;

    if(node["root"]["node"].IsDefined()) {
        type = "node";       
    } else if(node["root"]["scene"].IsDefined()) {
        type = "scene";
    }
    const Node n = node["root"][type];

    rhs.name = n["name"].as<std::string>();
    // ...
  }
};
```

Make sure that you have defined an appropriate copy-constructor for your `EngineNode` class:

```
class EngineNode {
public:
    EngineNode();
    EngineNode(const EngineNode &rhs); // Copy-constructor
    ~EngineNode();
// ...
};
```

That way, when your `EngineNode` is assigned in `YamlConfig::read`, it will make a valid copy if re-written like this:

```
EngineNode *YamlConfig::read(std::string path) {
    YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile(path);
    EngineNode *node = new EngineNode(doc.as<EngineNode>());

    // ...

    return node;
}
```

Anyone calling this function should be aware that this allocates a new `EngineNode` object on the heap. This object will probably need to be deallocated at some point by calling `delete` on it. Alternatively, you could rework your API to use smart pointers:

```
std::shared_ptr<EngineNode> YamlConfig::read(std::string path) {
    YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile(path);
    auto node = std::make_shared(doc.as<EngineNode>());

    // ...

    return node;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be doc.as<EngineNode*>() ? In YamlConfig::read. Because otherwise the templates won't match.

Comment: No. The point was to rewrite `decode` so that it takes a _reference_ to an EngineNode, not a pointer. This is because the `as` function allocates an EngineNode on the stack, not on the heap.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but you still have struct convert<EngineNode*>, so yaml-cpp doesn't know what to do with as<EngineNode>.